# boost::managed_mapped_file cannot allocate all of grown space

Tags: c++, boost, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to grow a memory mapped file, I successfully grow it, but I can't allocate all the extra space I've requested - I just get a `std::bad_alloc` instead.

Here is an example that shows the effect with g++ on Linux (I've seen the same on my 'real' code on MSVC too):

```
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/random_generator.hpp>

namespace
{
using MMapManager = boost::interprocess::basic_managed_mapped_file<
    char,
    boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::null_mutex_family,
                                         boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>,
                                         16u>,
    boost::interprocess::iset_index>;

using MMapAllocatorType = boost::interprocess::allocator<
    std::size_t,
    MMapManager::segment_manager>;

using MMapContainerType = boost::interprocess::vector<
    std::size_t,
    MMapAllocatorType>;

// I've measured this at 256 bytes for my example configuration, but it's not
// documented anywhere, so let's overcompensate
constexpr auto ManagedFileOverhead = 1024u;

boost::filesystem::path getTemporaryFilePath()
{
    auto ss = std::stringstream{};
    ss << "MMap_test_" << boost::uuids::random_generator{}();

    return boost::filesystem::temp_directory_path() / ss.str();
}
}

int main()
{
    // Create memory mapped file, initially for 100 items
    auto capacity = 100u;
    const auto size = (capacity * sizeof(std::size_t)) + ManagedFileOverhead;
    const auto path = getTemporaryFilePath();

    auto file = std::make_unique<MMapManager>(
        boost::interprocess::create_only,
        path.string().c_str(),
        size);
    auto data = file->construct<MMapContainerType>("data_")(file->get_segment_manager());

    // Fill with stuff
    data->reserve(capacity);
    for (auto i = 0u; i < capacity; ++i) {
        data->push_back(i);
    }

    // Let's grow to hold 162 items (100 * golden ratio)
    capacity = 162u;
    const auto newFileSize = (capacity * sizeof(std::size_t)) + ManagedFileOverhead;
    const auto oldFileSize = boost::filesystem::file_size(path);
    const auto extraBytes = newFileSize - oldFileSize;

    // Unmap from the process, and grow
    file.reset();
    MMapManager::grow(path.string().c_str(), extraBytes);

    // Reopen it to re-map it into this process
    file = std::make_unique<MMapManager>(
        boost::interprocess::open_only,
        path.string().c_str());
    data = file->find<MMapContainerType>("data_").first;

    // Allocate it all
    data->reserve(capacity); // Bang, you're dead

    // Close down
    file.reset();
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::filesystem::remove(path, ec);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Setting the reserve (after growing) to 155 items works, just one more triggers a `std::bad_alloc`.

Why does this not work?  Does growing incur extra management overhead within the mapped file causing me to run out of space earlier than expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're simply assuming too much about the allocators.

Growing the mapped file will happen in place. Growing the vector does not. So, while you would need only `extraBytes` *after* increasing the reserved size, during the reserve you need enough space to hold **both** the old and the new allocations.

Prove it either by using:

```
MMapManager::grow(path.string().c_str(), oldFileSize + extraBytes);
```

Or by clearing the old container first:

```
{
    auto file = std::make_unique<MMapManager>(boost::interprocess::open_only, path.string().c_str());
    file->destroy<MMapContainerType>("data_");
    auto data = file->construct<MMapContainerType>("data_")(file->get_segment_manager());
}

MMapManager::grow(path.string().c_str(), extraBytes);
```